# PrimeFaces <p:steps component's style is not getting displayed as expected

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I just wanted to try out the basic  prime faces component `<p:steps>`  from the prime faces showcase page:

https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menu/steps.xhtml

however, it does not work as expected. I copied the example from the page in my project into a separate facelets file.

But, instead of blue circles, as shown on the showcase page, I see  grey rectangles:

My facelet:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head></h:head>
<h:body>
    <f:facet name="first">
        <style type="text/css">
            body .ui-steps .ui-steps-item {
                width: 25%;
            }

            body .ui-state-highlight {
                text-shadow: none !important;
            }

            body .ui-steps.custom {
                margin-bottom: 30px;
            }

            body .ui-steps.custom .ui-steps-item .ui-menuitem-link {
                height: 10px;
                padding: 0 1em;
                overflow: visible;
                border: 1px solid #c8c8c8;
                display: block;
                background-color: #FFFFFF;
            }

            body .ui-steps.custom .ui-steps-item .ui-menuitem-link .ui-steps-number
                {
                background-color: #0081c2;
                color: #FFFFFF;
                display: inline-block;
                width: 30px;
                border-radius: 10px;
                margin-top: -10px;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
                position: relative;
                top: -3px;
            }

            body .ui-steps.custom .ui-steps-item .ui-menuitem-link .ui-steps-title {
                margin-top: -6px;
            }

            body .ui-steps.custom .ui-steps-item.ui-state-highlight .ui-menuitem-link .ui-steps-title
                {
                color: #555;
            }
            </style>
    </f:facet>
    <h3 style="margin-top: 0">Basic</h3>
    <p:steps>
        <p:menuitem value="Personal" />
        <p:menuitem value="Seat Selection" />
        <p:menuitem value="Payment" />
        <p:menuitem value="Confirmation" />
    </p:steps>
</h:body>
</html>
```

What I see in my browser is shown below:

[image: What I see in my browser]

What I am supposed to see accoroding to the PrimeFaces documentation is also shown below:

[image: What I am supposed to see accroding to the PrimeFaces documentation]

Comment: PrimeFaces showcase is using the "Nova Light" theme and it looks like you are using  Aristo or Omega theme?  It might be a matter of the CSS not overriding correctly with the Aristo or Omega theme and that CSS was designed for Nova or Luna themes.

Comment: This is too little information to go on. But as @Melloware is saying this is some kind of theme'ing issue. Use the inspector in the browser and see what CSS rules are actually being applied and if you are getting any errors on the console.

Comment: @Melloware I import PrimeFaces in my project by    <dependency>
   <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
   <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
   <version>7.0</version>
  </dependency> so I do not know what theme am I using. But when I use the example from the show case with copy and paste, I expect that it is working wihtout any additional adjustments!

Comment: What you are getting is the default theme. If you are not adding any additional themes it's the correct behavior. If you expect something else, then please file a bug on the issue tracker for the PrimeFaces Showcase here; https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces-showcase.

Comment: @AlexMi See this article on how to chnage your theme: https://mkyong.com/jsf2/primefaces/changing-theme-in-primefaces/  Then change it to "nova-light" which is the same theme the showcase is using.

Comment: @Melloware thank, you! I will read it in the next days and get back to you.!

Comment: @Melloware  I am not able to add the nova-light into my maven repository. Other themes, such as, for example, cupertino, I can add without any problems like this:     <dependency>
   <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
   <artifactId>cupertino</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.10</version>
  </dependency>  but NOT the Nova theme

Comment: @Melloware of all the themes available for download here:  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.primefaces.themes?p=1  there is nowhere a nova-ligth theme. Where / how could I find it?

Comment: Nova Light is built into the PrimeFaces JAR itself in PF 7+.  So you don't need any Maven Dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Interactive menu steps:

```
<p:steps activeIndex="1" styleClass="custom" readonly="false">
  <p:menuitem value="Personal" url="#"/>
  <p:menuitem value="Seat Selection" url="#"/>
  <p:menuitem value="Payment" url="#"/>
  <p:menuitem value="Confirmation" url="#"/>
</p:steps>
```

And place the CSS inside `h:head`(not compulsory) as:

```
 <h:head>
    <style type="text/css">
body .ui-steps .ui-steps-item {
    width: 25%;
}

body .ui-state-highlight {
    text-shadow: none !important;
}

body .ui-steps.custom {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

body .ui-steps.custom .ui-steps-item .ui-menuitem-link {
    height: 10px;
    padding: 0 1em;
    overflow: visible;
    border: 1px solid #c8c8c8;
    display: block;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

body .ui-steps.custom .ui-steps-item .ui-menuitem-link .ui-steps-number
    {
    background-color: #0081c2;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    position: relative;
    top: -3px;
}

body .ui-steps.custom .ui-steps-item .ui-menuitem-link .ui-steps-title {
    margin-top: -6px;
}

body .ui-steps.custom .ui-steps-item.ui-state-highlight .ui-menuitem-link .ui-steps-title
    {
    color: #555;
}
</style>
</h:head>
```

This approach should work.

Comment: Can you add some text to the answer and explain what relevant changes are you created